# OpenSSH directory is not accessible from Python processes in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm running Windows 10, fully up to date, and Python 3.7.

I can see the contents of c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH through both cmd and PowerShell, and can run the ssh command as normal.

However, if I start a Python process, this file is not visible, `os.path.exists("c:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH")` returns `False`. If I then start an instance of either cmd or Powershell in a subprocess that directory is not visible.

I'm trying to use Pipenv, a Python dependency management tool, which will instantiate a new shell with the correct environment as part of its process management.

This results in behaviour such as:

```
C:\Users\micro>dir c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
Volume in drive C is OS
Volume Serial Number is AEDD-9508

Directory of c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH

28/09/2017  15:49           851,456 ssh.exe
            1 File(s)        851,456 bytes
            0 Dir(s)  175,094,468,608 bytes free

C:\Users\micro>pipenv run dir c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\micro>
```

I've checked with the other users and they do not have this problem.

I've ensured all updates are applied to Windows, and have tried removing and re-adding the OpenSSH feature.

If anyone has a hint as to what information would be useful for debugging this I'd very much love to hear it.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: It's the 32 bit variant, it seems.

Comment: "I'm running Windows 10, fully up to date" - Please clarify this statement.  Are you running Windows 10 version 1903?  If you are the reason you are likely running into this problem is that you have installed the Windows Store version of Python.  Please edit your question to indicate this required information.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same issue, and I found the solution in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630224/python-does-not-find-system32

Windows is actually looking in SysWOW64; my code to fix this was

```
system32 = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative' if 
platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit' else 'System32')
listtest_path = os.path.join(system32, 'openSSH', 'ssh-keygen.exe')
subprocess.call([listtest_path])
```